# How to fix "TypeError: Swiper.initialize is not a function" Error in React Swiper with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, swiper.js, react-swiper

I try to use swiper in nextJs and Typescript. I want to edit styles with injectStyle but I get an error about initialize but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { register } from "swiper/element/bundle";
register();

const swiperRef: any = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
const Swiper = swiperRef.current;
Object.assign(Swiper, {
  modules: [Pagination],
  injectStyles: [
    `
    .swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets,
    .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-horizontal,
    .swiper-pagination-custom,
    .swiper-pagination-fraction {
      bottom: var(--swiper-pagination-bottom, 8px);
      top: var(--swiper-pagination-top, 220px) !important;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .swiper,
    swiper-container {
      overflow: visible !important;
    }

    .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
      background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, #475aea) !important;
    }

    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
      background: var(
        --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color,
        #475aea
      ) !important;
    }
    `,
  ],
});
Swiper.initialize();  <-- Error Here
}, []);
```

And in render:

```
<Swiper
  ref={swiperRef}
  init={false}
  pagination={true}
  modules={[Pagination]}
  className="mySwiper"
> ... </Swiper>
```

I try to fix it with Swiper Element help but I can't.
https://swiperjs.com/element#usage-with-react

Comment: you need to show what are you trying to do with the Swiper Element. What is not working? Your current code is incomplete. Within which component is the useEffect called?

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
  const swiperRef = useRef<HTMLLinkElement | any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {

      // Register Swiper web component
      register();
  
      if (swiperRef.current) {
        // Add event listener
        swiperRef.current.addEventListener('slidechange', (e: any) => {
          console.log(e.detail);
        });
    
        // Object with parameters
        const params = {
          // or pass it in on
          on: {
            slideChange(s) {
              console.log(s);
            },
          },
        };
    
        // Assign it to swiper element
        Object.assign(swiperRef.current!, params);
    
        // initialize swiper
        swiperRef.current.initialize();
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this interface to fix an error:

```
import { SwiperContainer } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

const swiperRef = useRef<SwiperContainer>(null);
```